# Check if optional parameter was passed to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I really would prefer to not rely on sentinel values such as `0`, `-1`, or `NULL` when testing if an optional parameter to a stored procedure was passed. Is there a definitive way to check?

For example, can I check if any of these sample parameters were specified in the call without assuming they were *not* passed with a particular value?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure
     @SampleStringParam VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,@SampleBooleanParam BIT = 0
    ,@MultiplicativeIdentity REAL = 1
    ,@MultiplicativeInverse REAL = -1
    ,@AdditiveIdentity REAL = 0
AS
...
```

Comment: No - there's no general way of distinguishing if  `@AdditiveIdentity` for example has the value `0` because the default was applied or because that value was passed explicitly.

Comment: No. You would need mandatory parameters and different procs.

Comment: No, and why would you care? Either way you are going to work with the default value unless another value was specified, that is the point of having default values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure
     @SampleStringParam VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,@SampleBooleanParam BIT = NULL
    ,@MultiplicativeIdentity REAL = NULL
    ,@MultiplicativeInverse REAL = NULL
    ,@AdditiveIdentity REAL = NULL
AS
IF @SampleBooleanParam IS NULL
--  @SampleBooleanParam DEFAULT
SET @SampleBooleanParam = 0
```

Comment: How do you believe this solves the question asked? There is no way of distinguishing if NULL was passed explicitly or added by the default.

Comment: NULL passed explicitly or added by default, it does not matter

Comment: It’s just another sentinel value which the question was specifically asking how to avoid.

Comment: Delete default values and always set value in execute proc :)

Comment: I turns out that even getting the default parameter value from the stored procedure definition is stupidly hard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47485321/2799848