# Get default value of stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, default-value, ssms-2012

I have created below stored procedure with default value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sample1] 
     @OrderID INT = 10285
AS
    SELECT ProductName, OrderID
    FROM Products P, [Order Details] Od
    WHERE Od.ProductID = P.ProductID 
      AND Od.OrderID = @OrderID
```

Tried to get default value (10285) of parameters using `sys.parameters`.

```
Select a.object_id, a.default_value
from sys.parameters a
inner join sys.types b on b.system_type_id = a.system_type_id
where Object_id = object_id('[dbo].[Sample1]')
```

But I got NULL as `default_value`, while I was expecting `10285` as `default_value`.

Is there any way to get default value?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that [Microsoft has neglected this topic](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/234143/populate-has-default-value-in-sys-parameters) and there is no trivial way to find parameters default values and even if a default value is present or not on a specific parameter:

> As we all know, T-SQL stored procedure parameter defaults are not
>   stored in sys.parameters, all_parameters, and system_parameters.  They
>   are also not exposed through sp_sproc_columns, sys.columns, or
>   sp_procedure_params_rowset.

Feedback from Microsoft:

> As posted by Tibor Karaszi, BOL document that "SQL Server only
>   maintains default values for CLR objects in this catalog view;
>   therefore, this  column has a value of 0 for Transact-SQL objects. To
>   view the default value of a parameter in a Transact-SQL object, query
>   the definition column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view, or use the
>   OBJECT_DEFINITION system function."
>
> We dont store even the bit that indicating parameter is of default
>   value in Yukon.

I have tested the first code snippet [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15786683/2780791) and it seems to work for your simple example:

```
SELECT  
      data3.name
    , [default_value] = REVERSE(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(
          data3.rtoken
        , CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(N',', data3.rtoken) > 0 
                THEN CHARINDEX(N',', data3.rtoken) + 1
            WHEN CHARINDEX(N')', data3.rtoken) > 0 
                THEN CHARINDEX(N')', data3.rtoken) + 1
            ELSE 1 
          END
        , LEN(data3.rtoken)
      )))
FROM (
    SELECT  
          data2.name
        , rtoken = REVERSE(
            SUBSTRING(ptoken
                    , CHARINDEX('=', ptoken, 1) + 1
                    , LEN(data2.ptoken))
                )
    FROM (
        SELECT  
              data.name
            , ptoken = SUBSTRING(
                  data.tokens
                , token_pos + name_length + 1
                , ISNULL(ABS(next_token_pos - token_pos - name_length - 1), LEN(data.tokens))
            )
        FROM (
            SELECT  
                  sm3.tokens
                , p.name
                , name_length = LEN(p.name)
                , token_pos = CHARINDEX(p.name, sm3.tokens)
                , next_token_pos = CHARINDEX(p2.name, sm3.tokens)
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                      sm2.[object_id]
                    , sm2.[type]
                    , tokens = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(sm2.tokens, ISNULL(CHARINDEX('SA', sm2.tokens) + 2, 0), LEN(sm2.tokens))) 
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                          sm.[object_id]
                        , o.[type]
                        , tokens = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(
                                      sm.[definition]
                                    , CHARINDEX(o.name, sm.[definition]) + LEN(o.name) + 1
                                    , ABS(CHARINDEX(N'AS', sm.[definition]))
                                 )  
                        ) 
                    FROM sys.sql_modules sm WITH (NOLOCK)
                    JOIN sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) ON sm.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
                    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
                    WHERE o.[type] = 'P '
                        AND s.name + '.' + o.name = 'dbo.Sample1'
                ) sm2
                WHERE sm2.tokens LIKE '%=%'
            ) sm3
            JOIN sys.parameters p WITH (NOLOCK) ON sm3.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
            OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT p2.name
                FROM sys.parameters p2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                WHERE p2.is_output = 0
                    AND sm3.[object_id] = p2.[object_id] 
                    AND p.parameter_id + 1 = p2.parameter_id
            ) p2
            WHERE p.is_output = 0
        ) data
    ) data2
    WHERE data2.ptoken LIKE '%=%'
) data3
```

However, it is really ugly for a task that one expects to be easily queryable from system views.

Answer (score 1):

I agree default stored procedure parameter values should be exposed via a SQL Server catalog view.

The T-SQL parsing method may work in many cases but is fragile. Consider using the TransactSQL ScriptDOM. Below is an example using a mix of PowerShell and C#. Not saying this will be perfect for all cases but it seems to process all the parameters I've thrown at it thusfar.

I used the `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll` assembly from my SSMS install in this example but it can be downloaded from the [NuGet Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom).

```
try
{
    Add-type -LiteralPath @("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll");
    Add-type `
        -ReferencedAssemblies @("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll") `
        -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;
using System.IO;
public static class ProcParser
{

    public static List<StoredProcedureParameter> GetStoredProcedureParameters(string storedProcedureDefinition)
    {

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(storedProcedureDefinition);
        var parser = new TSql140Parser(true);

        IList<ParseError> errors;
        TSqlFragment sqlFragment = parser.Parse(reader, out errors);

        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(`"Error parsing stored procedure definition`");
        }

        SQLVisitor sqlVisitor = new SQLVisitor();
        sqlFragment.Accept(sqlVisitor);

        return sqlVisitor.StoredProcedureParameters;

    }

}

internal class SQLVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
{

    public List<StoredProcedureParameter> StoredProcedureParameters = new List<StoredProcedureParameter>();

    public override void ExplicitVisit(ProcedureParameter node)
    {

        var p = StoredProcedureParameter.CreateProcedureParameter(node);
        StoredProcedureParameters.Add(p);

    }

}

public class StoredProcedureParameter
{
    public string ParameterName;
    public string ParameterType;
    public string ParameterDirection = null;
    public string DefaultParameterValue = null;

    public static StoredProcedureParameter CreateProcedureParameter(ProcedureParameter node)
    {
        var param = new StoredProcedureParameter();

        //parameter name
        param.ParameterName = node.VariableName.Value;

        //data type
        switch (((ParameterizedDataTypeReference)node.DataType).Parameters.Count)
        {
            case 0:
                if (node.DataType.Name.Identifiers.Count == 1)
                {
                    param.ParameterType = node.DataType.Name.Identifiers[0].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    //schema-qualified type name
                    param.ParameterType = node.DataType.Name.Identifiers[0].Value + `".`" + node.DataType.Name.Identifiers[1].Value;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                param.ParameterType = node.DataType.Name.Identifiers[0].Value + "(" + ((ParameterizedDataTypeReference)node.DataType).Parameters[0].Value + ")";
                break;
            case 2:
                param.ParameterType = node.DataType.Name.Identifiers[0].Value + "(" + ((ParameterizedDataTypeReference)node.DataType).Parameters[0].Value + "," + ((ParameterizedDataTypeReference)node.DataType).Parameters[1].Value + ")";
                break;
        }

        //default value
        if (node.Value != null)
        {
            param.DefaultParameterValue = node.ScriptTokenStream[node.LastTokenIndex].Text;
        }

        //direction
        if (node.Modifier == ParameterModifier.Output)
        {
            param.ParameterDirection = `"OUTPUT`";
        }
        else if (node.Modifier == ParameterModifier.ReadOnly)
        {
            param.ParameterDirection = `"READONLY`";
        }
        else
        {
            param.ParameterDirection = `"INPUT`";
        }

        return param;

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(ParameterName);
        sb.Append(`" `");
        sb.Append(ParameterType);
        if (DefaultParameterValue != null)
        {
            sb.Append(`" `");
            sb.Append(DefaultParameterValue);
        }
        sb.Append(`" `");
        sb.Append(ParameterDirection);
        return sb.ToString();

    }

}
"@

}
catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException]
{
  Write-Host "Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
  Write-Host "StackTrace: $($_.Exception.StackTrace)"
  Write-Host "LoaderExceptions: $($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions)"
  throw;
}

Function Get-ProcText($connectionString, $procName)
{
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString);
    $connection.Open();
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@ProcName);", $connection);
    $procNameParameter = $command.Parameters.Add((New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ProcName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 261)));
    $procNameParameter.Value = $procName;
    $procText = $command.ExecuteScalar();
    $connection.Close();
    return $procText;
}

############
### main ###
############
try {

    # get proc text definition from database
    $procText = Get-ProcText `
        -connectionString "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI" `
        -procName "dbo.testproc";

    # parse parameters from proc text
    $procParameters = [ProcParser]::GetStoredProcedureParameters($procText);

    # display parameter values
    foreach($procParameter in $procParameters)
    {
        Write-Host "ParameterName=$($procParameter.ParameterName)";
        Write-Host "`tParameterType=$($procParameter.ParameterType)";
        Write-Host "`tDefaultParameterValue=$($procParameter.DefaultParameterValue)";
        Write-Host "`tParameterDirection=$($procParameter.ParameterDirection)";
    }

}
catch {
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Alexei's brilliant solution, but one of my variables, and a comment on a parameter both had the word 'class' in it and I couldn't for the life of me figure out why it broke.  I finally realized that the word 'class' has 'AS' in it.  So the key to avoiding that situation is to differentiate the AS keyword denoting the beginning of the body of the sp from random AS strings in the parameter section.  I found a way that works for me, and might work for others.  It relies on the fact that the AS keyword is on its own line prededed by CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) and succeeded by CHAR(13) + CHAR(10).  So I modified these two lines:

```
                , tokens = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(sm2.tokens, ISNULL(CHARINDEX(CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'SA' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), sm2.tokens) + 2, 0), LEN(sm2.tokens))) 

                    , tokens = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(
                                  sm.[definition]
                                , CHARINDEX(o.name, sm.[definition]) + LEN(o.name) + 1
                                , ABS(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'AS' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), sm.[definition]))
                             )
```