# How to find the required parameters for a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was not able to find in which system view the default values of stored procedure are recorded.
For example, if we have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[...]
(
    @A BIGINT 
   ,@B TINYINT = 2
   ,@C VARCHAR(12) = 'test'
)
AS
```

Is there a place where I can see that parameter `@A` is required and/or `@B` and `@C` have default values?

Comment: Before someone suggests this `sys.parameters` column `default_value` is only relevant for CLR procs not TSQL ones

Comment: The default parameter value is not exposed by a catalog view. Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484834/get-default-value-of-stored-procedure-parameter) will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get default value of stored procedure parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484834/get-default-value-of-stored-procedure-parameter)

Comment: @DanGuzman and Larnu Thanks, it confirms there is no clear way to get them.

Comment: They could be parsed from the procedure definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get default value of stored procedure parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484834/get-default-value-of-stored-procedure-parameter) See also https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/sql-performance/paramparser-1

Answer (score 0):

You can find them here

```
select pa.* from sys.procedures pr 
join sys.parameters pa on pr.object_id = pa.object_id
```

Comment: How does this tell you if the parameter has a default value?

Comment: These are the results for the proc given in the question https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=add91d180b599004d864fed3881fa463